# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor UI

Tags: java, android, sdk, editor, adobe

How to Resolve this issue? i already integrated multidex by following all steps properly but app still crashes sometimes

```
07-14 16:28:38.103 16031-16031/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: release sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-14 16:28:38.163 8303-8303/com.randomsoft.love.poetry.photo.editor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.randomsoft.love.poetry.photo.editor, PID: 8303
                                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity
                                                                                           at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageIntent$Builder.<init>(AdobeImageIntent.java:191)
                                                                                           at com.randomsoft.love.poetry.photo.editor.WorkONIMAGEActivity$17.onClick(WorkONIMAGEActivity.java:1668)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Here is my dependencies from gradle file and every dependency is only once used and their versions are also same for support libraries

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile project(':CropPhotoCommon')
    compile 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.jrummyapps:colorpicker:2.1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    /* 4) Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'

    /* Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'
}
```

Comment: use same version of dependencies in library and App at build.gradle and make sure every dependencies is used once in a project.

Answer (score 0):

this is done cause class is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.
and also add some class from CSDK example

Comment: how to look into build time and runtime my app is already published on play store after signing apk and also classes from CSDK are not within my app, these are used by dependencies at runtime